# Parse.com Push Service Battery Impact

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging, ppns

I cannot use `GCM` and I am looking for solutions to support Push service in my application.

I saw `PPNS` from `Parse.com` and I am now using it. I starts a consistent `websocket` connection and checks the connection every 15min. And it also checks it on every device wake-up.

What is the approximate battery impact of just this `PushService` system?

Is anyone using it and tested it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** That's how push notification works. Don't worry about the battery usage if it's a required feature in your app.

**Long version:**
From what I understand (and indeed, have developed on my own App using my own MQ), that's what most/all other APIs that handle push notifications do, i.e. they maintain a persistent connection to an MQ of sorts (ActiveMQ, MSMQ, etc.) and subscribe to a specific topic which "pushes" messages to clients.

All of them require a WakeLock in order to keep this connection live in the event the phone is "sleeping" or network connection is recovered in order to make sure notifications are delivered. Some of them even maintain some level of persistence in case a message arrives when connection is lost so that they can playback the messages when they reconnect (although this would be an expensive feature in terms of server resources).

Your users most likely already have a WakeLock in one/many of their installed apps (WhatsApp, Skype, etc. -- You can check this by looking at the permissions WhatsApp requires for instance. One of them would be "preventing the phone from sleeping").

This in turn means that adding an extra WakeLock will have no material effect as the phone never REALLY goes to complete sleep anyway. If yours is the only app that has this WakeLock, then there would be a real cost to the battery but it's unavoidable unless you make sure you persist messages in the queue and only display notifications when the user unlocks the phone which is (1) expensive to maintain on your queue and (2) not very convenient as the user will miss notifications unless they're already actively using the phone so background notifications will go amiss.

I also don't imagine battery life would be hugely impacted if you're simply pinging the server every 15 minutes or so (the interval is usually the keep-alive time for the underlying message queue).

This link should help you understand how a local implementation for messaging works and should give you an idea why the ping is necessary and why you would want to maintain that WakeLock:

http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599

*edit: added TL;DR*

Comment: As far as I know, Whatsapp and all the similar apps uses GCM. GCM is holding that persistant connection once for all the apps. So adding another basically makes the battery effect double.
In my case, our users use our special tablets that runs AOSP without Google Services and there is only our applications installed.

Comment: Secondly, I know that GCM and all of the systems are similar but I am also curious about the efficiency of them. Spesifically Parse.com in this case. Is PPNS from Parse.com written efficiently? That's the question.

Comment: There are two things here that can have a detrimental effect on the battery usage: (1) preventing the phone from completely hibernating/sleeping by allowing the network to work in the background and (2) the ping to your MQ. The first point will have a much higher effect on the battery than point #2. GCM and all similar services using MQs will aquire a WakeLock. You can have as many of these locks as you want, the effect is the same, i.e the phone/tablet doesn't sleep. If you're worried about the ping and reconnect when the connection status changes, I wouldn't worry about it personally ...

Comment: [Continued] but I would do some test just to be sure. I highly doubt one ping every 15 minutes would be such a battery consuming activity to be perfectly honest but I wouldn't know for sure since I haven't done any detailed analysis. However, I would be more worried about the first point (WakeLock) if your app is the only app running on the tablets and therefore, potentially, your tablets did not have a WakeLock before but now require one. This one would be a deal breaker for you if battery preservation is a must.

Comment: Did you have a way to measure battery impact? I'm also concerned by this. My app will have to run on devices that have Google services but we are going full with parse and thus we will be using their push service unless I found out this cause an impact on the battery life.